# What language that envoy proxy uses?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

What is the programming language that below envoy uses?

```
  operation: INSERT_BEFORE
  value: # lua filter specification
   name: envoy.lua
   config:
     inlineCode: |
       function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
         -- Make an HTTP call to an upstream host with the following headers, body, and timeout.
         local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
          "lua_cluster",
          {
           [":method"] = "POST",
           [":path"] = "/acl",
           [":authority"] = "internal.org.net"
          },
         "authorize call",
         5000)
       end
```

Is it possible to use python in place of above language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Lua. Read more [here](https://www.lua.org/about.html).

Comment: We cannot use python in place of lua in above filter right?

Comment: No. The documentation shows how it works and it doesn't mention support for Python. https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/lua_filter#overview